# Does filterKeys cause a stack overflow?

Tags: scala, collections, stack-overflow

As I understand, method `filterKeys` of `MapLike` creates a *wrapper* over the original map. So, if I execute the code below `m` will be a chain of 10K wrappers and the original map.

```
var m = Map(1 -> "one", 2 -> "two")
for(1 <- 0 until 10000) {m = m.filterKeys(_%2 == 0)}
```

Now I thought that an invocation of `m.contains` caused a stack overflow but it does not happen. Could you explain what is going on in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your loop only executes 1 time, if I copy verbatim. Because of this you are only creating a single wrapper, so what was intended to be a chain of 10000 wrappers is just a chain of 1. It might be a typo, but the loop,

```
for(1 <- 0 until 10000) {m = m.filterKeys(_%2 == 0)}
```

should probably be

```
for(i <- 0 until 10000) {m = m.filterKeys(_%2 == 0)}
```

Aside from that, Daniel is right; fitlerKeys does produce what is essentially a wrapper. It took me more than 10k iterations, but I did manage to create a StackOverflowError.

Comment: Thanks. I fixed the typo you noticed and run the loop more iterations. Now the stack overflow _does_ occur. Well, the _filterKeys_ is really dangerous ...

Comment: @Michael: *filterKeys* is only dangerous if you plan on performing it thousands of times without anything in-between. In most cases, its lazy behavior is actually desirable.

Comment: Yeah, this highlights a potential for misusing functional programming. In this case, it's probably a good idea to ensure that m is always its own collection, maybe along the lines of `m = Map() ++ m.filterKeys(_%2 == 0)`

Answer (score 2):

I could not reproduce the stack overflow, but here's what happen:

```
override def filterKeys(p: A => Boolean): Map[A, B] = new DefaultMap[A, B] {
  override def foreach[C](f: ((A, B)) => C): Unit = for (kv <- self) if (p(kv._1)) f(kv)
  def iterator = self.iterator.filter(kv => p(kv._1))
  override def contains(key: A) = self.contains(key) && p(key)
  def get(key: A) = if (!p(key)) None else self.get(key)
}
```

Note that there's no copying of values: the new class simply add rules to four methods that will change how they work to reflect the filter you added. Since you repeatedly apply `filterKeys` (10000 times), that means you have 10000 classes, each pointing to the previous one, and the first pointing to your original map.

Calling one of the above methods (directly or indirectly) on the final class will, therefore, call 10000 nested methods, which can certainly produce a stack overflow if your stack is small enough.

Answer (score 2):

I was able to cause it to Stack Overflow like this (Scala 2.9.1)

```
scala> var m = Map(1 -> "one", 2 -> "two")
scala> for (_ <- 0 until 1000000) { m = m.filterKeys(_ % 2 == 0) }
scala> m.contains(1)
huge stack trace
```

You can, of course, avoid the stack trace by forcing `filterKeys` to actually do its work at each step:

```
scala> var m = Map(1 -> "one", 2 -> "two")
scala> for (_ <- 0 until 1000000) { m = Map() ++ m.filterKeys(_ % 2 == 0) }
scala> m.contains(1)
res1: Boolean = false
```